# Is make a part of GNU tool chain?

Tags: gcc, makefile, gnu-toolchain

As far as I understand, GNU tool chain, whose main purpose is to convert source code into executable files consists of gcc compiler collection(.c to .o conversion), linkers and locators(ld).
I also understand that a make file contains just a set of instructions for the compiler to read and also that make in itself invokes gcc for compilation.
My question is, is make file an alternative to GNU tool chain or is it a part of the tool chain and shipped with it?
Also, if one compiles .c files with make, does it still go through the standard five steps(preprocessing, compiling, assembling, linking and locating)?

Comment: does this answer your question: [gnu make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read documentation of [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/). and download its source code, whose copyright is owned by the FSF. So GNU make is definitely (like [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) or [GNU binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) or [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/)) part of the [GNU project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Project).

Be aware that (at least on GNU/Linux) `make`  is *running* GCC compilation commands.

In some cases, [GNU autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/) is also used. Then the `Makefile`-s could be generated by the (autoconf generated) `configure` script.

To understand more, try building some GNU software, such as [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), from its source code. You might be interested by Linux source distributions such as [gentoo](https://gentoo.org/) or in following [linuxfromscratch](https://linuxfromscratch.org/).

To understand even more, try *contributing some code* to some GNU software. Also try running `make -p` to understand the rules known to  [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/).

Comment: Thanks you for answering. Guess I should always go for the documentation first!